# Show/Hide window from process handle on Mono

Tags: linux, mono, pinvoke

I am writing an application in VB.Net to be run on Mono.

I can close a window from a process like so:

```
Dim procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Firefox")
procs(0).CloseMainWindow()
```

However I want to be able to show/hide this window as well, but I have to do so in a way that is compatible with Mono running on linux, so the common way I have seen of doing so through P/Invoke will not work

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I've re-tagged this since you are asking about Linux rather than Windows. You already have a solution for Windows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks